Does the print of readframes(n) of wave library return the audio samples in hexadecimal form?
When I print the result of the first audio frame by doing track.readframes(1), I get b'\xfb\xff\xfb\xfe'. My track is stereo so we know that we have 2 channels where each channel has 1 sample. Does it mean that the left channel sample is : 'fbff' and the right one is 'fbfe'?

Hi! This seems to be more of a general programming than a signal processing question. Also, the byte order actually depends on the type of data in your WAV, so there's no single answer to your question.

Thanks for your answer Marcus. I am actually trying to read the frames of a wav song and then get the samples of it. The track is stereo so we know that each channel should have 1 sample that's why I assumed the above.

don't assume - you don't say which of the multiple python-wrapped audio file reading libraries you use, but its documentation should tell you exactly how to figure that out.

Oh, I said that on the title, I am using the wave library and unfortunately, its documentation and google info are poor.

ah you mean the python3 builtin wave module with "wave library", sorry, I was being a bit thick there. Yeah, the documentation could be better. But it's all there: getsampwidth will tell you how much bits there are per sample, and they are indeed in order. However, don't use the wave module in a cross-platform context; it always assumes Little-endian data, and that's not true for all wav files. Also, it can't deal with any compressed audio, doesn't even try to support you guessing whether a 4-byte sample is a 32 bit little endian integer, bit endian integer, or floating point number,…

… in other words, it's just bad. scipy.io.wavfile.read is slightly better, but still far from a well-supported audio file reader for anything but LPCM WAV files as implicitly standardized ca 1994. You probably want to install python-soundfile; https://python-soundfile.readthedocs.io/en/0.11.0/

So if sampwidth is 2 then we have 2 samples which are 'fbff' and 'fbfe' right?

can't tell you, needs info on getsampwidth, and you need to hope that this file is in one of the formats that wave will actually correctly read. Probably, yes. Again, I've read the source code, and I don't trust this module to work correctly with modern wave files.

I did getsampwidth and it returned 2(if it read correctly). So I am guessing that first sample is '\xfb\xff' (fbff) and second one 'xfb\xfe' (fbfe).

yes, we both need to guess, because the library you use is insufficient at parsing headers. Really, use something else. This is not the proudest thing that Python ships.

Perfect. Thank you for your time!
